# When exporting 'Customers Main File' from Magento 2.4.3-p3 the CSV doesn't appear in the download list, even after relevant fixes

Tags: magento2.4.3

System->Export->Customers Main File, CSV, nothing else changed, Continue. I get the message 'Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon. Make sure your cron job is running to export the file'

After a long time, 24 hours or more, the file is not showing up in the list.

I have tried:

`php bin/magento cron:run`

`php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor&`

Setting 'Add Secret Keys to URLs' to 'No', via Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Also removed the var and generated folders and redeployed.

The export file is not present in the var/export directory, but the 'Customers Addresses' file is added and available in the export list in the Admin.

Is there anything else I can try?